# how to turn on CodeFolding for a given jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, code-folding

How can you turn code folding back on for a given Jupyter notebook?

For some reason in my Jupyter notebooks, sometimes when I reload the notebook, code folding will get turned off even though it's still in my `Nbextensions Configuration`... I am unable to sort out how to turn it back on for a current notebook, even though when I create new notebooks, code folding is there for markdown cells.